# how to invoke different controller in the same form

Tags: java, spring

I am newbie to spring framework.My requirement is,i have a form it has start date and end date textfield and two submit buttons,i invoke two separate controller for the button click.But form tag accepts only one action attribute.I do this in struts2 by using formaction attribute in button tag.But i don't know how to do it in spring?

Below is my code

```
<form action="projectreport" method="get">
<label>Start Date</label>
<input type="text" name="stdate" id="stdate"/>
<label>End Date</label>
<input type="text" name="enddate" id="enddate"/>
<input type="submit" value="GenerateProjectReport"/>
<input type="submit" value="GenerateUserReport"/>
</form>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: @Karthikeyan,i added my code

Answer (score 0):

i'm not familiar to struts, but I don't under stand why u try to direct two different url for a form? see action [action documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_form_action.asp)

I think what u really need is handle request in two ways base on parameters. So why didn't u format parameters when button clicked, then submit request. U can dispatch to appropriate interface in controllers.

```
<form action="url">
<button name="buttonA"></button>
<button name="buttonB"></button>
</form>
</body>
<script>
    buttonA.clcik:function(){
        params :{
            paraA: xx,
            paraB: xx
        }
        form.submit();
    }
    buttonB.clcik:function(){
        params :{
            paraC: xx,
            paraD: xx
        }
        form.submit();
    }
</script>
```

Another way is submit to different url not using form.submit.